# Inner Product Space of Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, transpose

How do we show that when  A is symmetric i.e the transpose of A is equal to A itself where A is a 2x2 matrix with λ2>λ1>0 THEN 
=a.(A(b)) is an inner product  ?

I think I need to work in the basis of eigenvectors in order to prove this.I just don't know how to process any further. All the best

Comment: "= a.(A(b)) is an inner product space" ? That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, and I've taught linear algebra a bunch of times. Can you tell me the definition of "inner product space" that you're working with? (You can click "edit" below your question to add details like this one.)

Comment: I fixed the issue. I meant an inner product.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

If we want to define our inner product.

$\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = \mathbf x^TA\mathbf y$

We need to show that by this definition our inner product has:

Symmetry: (if our vectors are real, conjugate symmetry if they are complex)

$\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = \langle \mathbf y,\mathbf x\rangle$

Since $\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = \mathbf x^TA\mathbf y$ is a real $1\times 1$ matrix

$\mathbf x^TA\mathbf y = (\mathbf x^TA\mathbf y)^T \\
\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = \mathbf x^TA\mathbf y = (\mathbf x^TA\mathbf y)^T = \mathbf y^TA^T\mathbf x = \mathbf y^TA\mathbf x = \langle \mathbf y,\mathbf x\rangle$

Linearity:

$\langle \mathbf x+\mathbf z,\mathbf y\rangle = \langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle + \langle \mathbf z,\mathbf y\rangle$

$\mathbf (\mathbf x+ \mathbf z)^TA\mathbf y =\mathbf (\mathbf x^T+ \mathbf z^T)A\mathbf y =  \mathbf x^TA\mathbf y + \mathbf z^TA\mathbf y$

$\langle a\mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = a\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle$

and postive definite:

$\|\mathbf x\|^2  = \langle \mathbf x,\mathbf x\rangle > 0$ for all $x \ne \mathbf 0$

The last one is the one that requires the eigenvectors to be greater than $0$

let $\mathbf x = a\mathbf v_1 + b\mathbf v_2$ where $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2$ are normalized eigenvectors

$\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf x\rangle = a^2\lambda_1 + b^2\lambda_2$

Comment: Excuse my lack of understanding but how do we prove this 4 properties in this particular example ?